# How to specify default value for form input using Spring and Freemarker

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using Spring MVC and Freemarker.

I have created a form and I want to put a default value into a formInput

```
<@spring.formInput 'search.value' ''/>
```

But the documentation is a bit weak and I can't figure out how to specify the default value for the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to set the value in the backing form, and not in template.